# Exercise 1.10 from Stein's Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> $1.10$. Show that $$4\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} = 4\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \Delta$$
>
> where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian $\Delta = \displaystyle{\frac{\partial ^ 2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^ 2}{\partial y^2}}$

What I've tried:

Let $f = u + i v$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial  z} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial  x} + \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial  y}) \implies \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \overline{z} \partial z}=\frac{1}{4}[\frac{\partial}{\partial  x}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial  x} + \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial  y})-\frac{1}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial  x} + \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial  y})] = \frac{1}{4}(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial  x^2} + \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial  x \partial y} - \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial  y \partial x} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial  y^2})$$

My question is:

Why $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial  y \partial x} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial  x \partial y}}$ ?

I know that for $\mathbb{R^2}$ function needs to be $\mathcal{C}^2$- class to work. But why in $\mathbb{C}$ this works?

Comment: You are correct, we do need to assume that $\partial_1\partial_2 f=\partial_2\partial_1 f$, for which assuming $f$ is $C^2$ is sufficient

Comment: @Lorago yes, but exercise don't says any remark about function. It also works if $f$ is not $C^2$ ? I mean, this works for any function in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No, since $\mathbb{C}$ is just $\mathbb{R}^2$ this will not work in general. Just take any function $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ where the partial derivatives do not commute, then let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be given by $f(x+iy)=\tilde{f}_1(x,y)+i\tilde{f}_2(x,y)$, and you have your counterexample. There is nothing different about functions $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, unless you start imposing conditions like complex differentiability and such

Comment: @Lorago thanks you! And another two small questions. For a holomorphic function this relation is valid? Holomorphic functions are $C^\infty$?

Comment: Yep indeed. The fact that complex differentiable functions are infinitely complex differentiable (and consequently $C^\infty$ in the real sense as well) is one of the most important results in complex analysis, however it's not necessarily trivial (in particular, you'll need Cauchy's integral theorem)

Comment: Do not post the same question several times.